# Как подключить .js в bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass, bootstrap4

здравствуйте я начал изучать js после html.css.bootstrap.подскажите как подключить .js к бутстрапу.Отдельно пишу .js работает.

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду подключить свой js файл к html, где подключен bootstrap?

Answer (score 1):

```
<body>

    <!-- Контент страницы -->
    ...  
    <!-- Подключаем ваш Скрипт -->
      <script src="YourScript.js"> </script>

    <!-- Подключаем jQuery -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Подключаем плагин Popper (необходим для работы компонента Dropdown и др.) -->
    <script src="js/popper.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Подключаем Bootstrap JS -->    
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

В таком порядке:

```html
<html lang="en"><head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>your_title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="libs/bootstrap-4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/your_stylesheet.css">
    <script src="libs/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="libs/bootstrap-4.4.1/js/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="libs/bootstrap-4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<!-- body start here -->
<!-- body code here -->
<script src="js/your_script.js"></script>
<!-- body end here -->
```